# killall command older-than option

Tags: bash, kill-process

I'd like to ask about experience with the killall program, namely if anyone used the -o, --older-than CLI option.
We've recently encountered a problem that processes were killed under the hood by a command: "killall --older-than 1h -r chromedriver"

Killall was simply killing everything that matched regardless of the age. While killall man page is quite straightforward:

-o, --older-than
              Match only processes that are older (started before) the time specified.  The time is specified as a float then a unit.   The  units
              are s,m,h,d,w,M,y for seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, Months and years respectively.

I wonder if this was a result of some false assumption or killall bug or something else.

Other posts here suggest a lot more complicated command involving sed, piping, etc which seem to work though.

Thanks,
Zdenek

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're referring to the Linux incarnation of `killall`, coming from the PSmisc package.  Looking at the sources, it appears that some conditions for selecting PIDs to kill are AND-ed together, while others are OR-ed.  `-r` is one of the conditions that is OR-ed with the others.  I suspect the authors themselves can't really explain their intention there...

Comment: yes, sorry, I should have provided a little more details, so: it's on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-46-generic x86_64), psmisc: /usr/bin/killall, psmisc 22.20-1ubuntu2. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/psmisc/bugs/62/ looks like it's even known issue already.